# Can't see my captcha in my Joomla 3

Tags: joomla, addition, captcha

I already changed system>global configuration>default captcha>captcha-recaptcha,took my private key and public key from google.com/recaptcha,pasted them to my captcha plug in but there is no result,just see the word captcha and no more!

Comment: Do you get any errors in firebug? Is the plugin enabled?

Comment: here were some Captcha issues that have been solved in the latest version of Joomla so update if you haven't already.

Comment: OHHH THAAAAAAAAAAANKS a looooooooooooot!!!!!!!!!!!Installed new version and issue is gone!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here were some Captcha issues that have been solved in the latest version of Joomla so update if you haven't already. – Neil Robertson